Route [login] not defined in Laravel 10
working with Laravel 10 and passport authentication. I have following api route list as well
api.php
Route::prefix('v1')->group(function (){
    Route::post('/login',[AuthController::class,'login']);
    Route::post('/register',[AuthController::class,'register']);

    Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function () {
        Route::post('/logout',[AuthController::class, 'logout']);
        Route::get('/users/{id}',[AuthController::class, 'show']);
    });
    
});


and My auth.php is like
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'passport',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

AuthController.php
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
           
            "email" => "required",
            "password" => "required",
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails())
            return send_error('Validation error', $validator->errors(), 422);

            $credentials = $request->only('email','password');

            if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
                $user = Auth::user();
                $data['name'] = $user->name;
                $data['access_token'] = $user->createToken('accessToken')->accessToken;

                return send_response('You are successfully logedin.',$data);
            }else {
                return send_error('Unauthorized','',401);
            }


    }

    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            "name" => "required|min:4",
            "email" => "required|email|unique:users",
            "password" => "required|min:6"
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails())
            return send_error('Validation error', $validator->errors(), 422);

            try {

                $user = User::create([
                    'name' => $request->name,
                    'email' => $request->email,
                    'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
                ]);

                $data = [
                    'name' => $user->name,
                    'email' => $user->email
                ];

                return response()->json([
                    'status' => true,
                    'message' => 'User Registration Sucess!',
                    'name' => $user->name

                ]);

                return send_response('User Registration Sucess!', '$data');

            }catch (Exception $e) {
                // return response()->json([
                //     'message' => $e->getMessage()
                // ], $e->getCode());

                return send_error($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
            }
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        return 'test';
    }

I use postman api for loggin and it is working fine. but when I use logout function postman generate following error message
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined. in file F:\2024\Authentication System\backend\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator.php on line 477 
how to fix this problem?
I need fine answers for this problem

What does AuthController::logout() do?

public function logout(Request $request)
{
return 'test';
}

did you define a login route name?

@krisgjika yes check my api.php

I don't see a route with name login. My guess is you are trying to access an auth protected route and you are being redirected to login route, but you have no such route

@krisgjika how to fixed this issue?

"when I use logout function" How do you do that? What do you send to the server to prove that you are logged in?

@Olivier well I could register and logedin succssfully using postman. but problem with logout. please see My AuthController

That does not answer my question.

Your using route('login') and it gives this error:

Route [login] not defined.

Just put the name() on the route like this:
Route::post('/login',[AuthController::class,'login'])->name('login');

Check the docs here.

now got Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: The GET method is not supported for route api/v1/login. Supported methods: POST. in file F:\2024\Authentication  error but I am using POST for login route

you can't redirect to a POST route
